# what is the proper interpretation of "or", does it mean earlier or later if not specified

Tags: phrase-meaning

If a phrase say you may terminate an agreement in 10 years or when 12 units have been sold, does this mean that you may terminate on the earlier  of 10 years or when 12 units have been sold or the later of 10 years or when 12 units have been sold?

Comment: Usually these kinds of stipulations include the clause ***whichever comes first***.  And that's the way one would typically interpret it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legalese and logic and contracts, not about English Language and Usage.

Comment: I don't know if I'm agreeing the question should be closed, but the question is about legalese, contracts, and perhaps logic. The legal arguments could hinge on whether or not the 'or' *might be interpreted as conjunctive or disjunctive* by one or more of the parties to the contract. As the legal definition of 'conjunctive' in The Free Dictionary makes explicit, ["2. There are many cases in law, where the conjunctive and is used for the disjunctive or, and vice versa."](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Conjunctive). Symbolic logic obviates the problem by using different symbols.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, earlier. If it were the later, both conditions would have to be met and "and" would be more appropriate and less ambiguous than "or."

Answer (score 0):

This is a situation where the meaning of the provision depends on the underlying logic of the either/or structure it uses. First let's restate the provision in the contract, as you gave it above:

> You may terminate this agreement in 10 years or when 12 units have been sold.

Imagine this scenario: Ten years have passed, but you have sold only six units. Can you terminate the contract under the terms of the specified provision? Yes, because the prerequisite that ten years have passed or twelve units have been sold has been satisfied.

Now imagine this scenario: Five years have passed but you have already sold twelve units. Can you terminate the contract under the terms of the specified provision? Yes, because the prerequisite that ten years have passed or twelve units have been sold has been satisfied.

The logic of the sentence is as simple as that. As James McLeod points out in his answer, the only way the provision would not have been satisfied in either of the two scenarios I've presented here is if both criteria identified in the provision had to be satisfied—that is, if the provision had stated

> You may terminate this agreement after 10 years if at least 12 units have been sold.